# How to get a Table Row to Which Belongs the Name I'm Looking For?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

So, I'm running casperjs through Windows' command line and I'm trying to search for a name in a table and get the row to which it belongs.

For example: If I'm searching for the name "Pete" and it's on the 4th line, it should return 4.

As the name is the fist element of each row in the table I was thinking about getting the page's source code and parsing everything beetween  and  so I could get the name and compare it to what I have, if it's not equal I would just do a i++ and go on to the next row (i being the row's number).

I couldn't find any way to get the source code, if I could I would certainly be able to parse it.

Using pseudo-code it should be something like this:

```
function searchForName(desiredName) {
 var i = 1;
 while(desiredName != nameIFoundOnTheColumn(i)) {
   i++;
 }
 return i;
}
```

So, how can I get the source using JavaScript on a headless browser like PhantomJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used a simple function called `this.getHTML()` on Casper which I haven't seen before on Casper's documentation. Then I parsed the desired tags using another function to get what's between two tags.